# Javascript variable value passing from dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a table in javascript, where each row is to pass a different variable to the same function when the text is clicked. However, the function only receives the last value of the table no-matter which link is pressed:

```
function PrintTable(data){
    var col=data.mean[0].length;
    var row=data.mean.length;
    var t_id = document.getElementById("tablehtml");
    buffer='';
    t_id.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', buffer);
    for(var r = 0; r < row; r++){
        buffer = "<tr>";
        for(var c = 0; c < col ; c=c+2){
            fplot=data.mean[r][c];
            eplot=data.mean[r][c+1];
            buffer += "<td><a onclick=PlotGraph(fplot)>"+fplot+"</a></td><td><p>"+eplot+"</p></td>";
        }
        buffer += "</tr>";
        t_id.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', buffer);
    }
}
```

The data variable passed to the function (PrintTable) is an array like

```
[[900.0, -21.318],
 [950.0, -21.306]]
```

With the data shown above, the *PlotGraph* function only receives 950.

How can this be fixed, or done in another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `buffer += "<td><a onclick=PlotGraph(" + fplot + ")>"+fplot+"</a></td><td><p>"+eplot+"</p></td>";` on the 12th line of the code you posted.